# How can I put ajax form within post form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to have ajax form in order to validate whether if username is already taken when a user is trying to sign up.

Obviously, regular form is consisted of regular post form.
There are ordinary fields such as Name, Username, Email, and Password in that.

For this Username section, I want to add the button to validate.

But I have no idea how it goes if I'm doing it separately from regular post form.

It becomes something this?

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>

    <%= f.text_field :username, :placeholder => 'username' %></div>

    <%= form_for(current_user, :url => {:controller => "users", :action => "username_check" }, :remote => true) do |f| %>
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Check if availavle</button>
    <% end %>

    <div class="username_check_message">
        <%= render :partial => "users/username_check_message" %>
    </div>

    <%= button_tag( :class => "btn btn-large btn-primary") do %>
        Sign Up
    <% end %>        

<% end %>
```

Comment: By the way, just so you know, having a form inside another form is NOT valid HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can should show a `link` instead inner form and just bind `onclick` event of the link with js in which you can create ajax function.

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :username, :placeholder => 'username' %>

  <a href="javascript:;" class="btn" id="chk">Check if available</a>

  <div class="username_check_message">
    <%= render :partial => "users/username_check_message" %>
  </div>

  <%= button_tag( :class => "btn btn-large btn-primary") do %>
    Sign Up
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

JS code to bind click event

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#chk').click(function() {
      $.ajax({
          url: '/users/username_check',
          type: 'get',
          data: 'uname=' + $('#username').val(), // where 'username' is id of username text_field
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(data) {
              if(data.valid == 'true') {
                  $('.username_check_message').text('Valid');
              } else {
                  $('.username_check_message').text('Invalid');
              }
          }
      });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks but how do you pass param of username to ajax?

Comment: `data: 'uname=' + $('#username').val()` it is sending entered username as 'uname'. You can access it in you action as `params[:uname]`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to submit a for using ajax. You can use the remote option for that.

[You can check this guide on how to use it.](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html)

Comment: He is already using `:remote => true` in inner form, which he wants to be ajaxified. That is not the problem. Problem is that, when he will click any of the button within the outer form, it will submit the outer form without waiting for inner form's response